# Unable to install latest HWE for 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, hardware-enablement-stack

Following the instructions at [1404_HWE_EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL) and [LTSEnablementStack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), I am unable to upgrade my graphics stack. My current HWE stack is out of date as of the fourth, so I'd like to upgrade for security reasons.

`/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

When I try running the upgrade command, here's what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial : Depends: libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1) but it is not going to be installed
 xserver-xorg-lts-xenial : Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-xenial but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libegl1-mesa-lts-xenial but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libgles2-mesa-lts-xenial but it is not going to be installed
                           Recommends: libgles1-mesa-lts-xenial but it is not going to be installed
                           Conflicts: libegl1-mesa (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libglapi-mesa:i386 (>= 0~)
                           Conflicts: libgles2-mesa (>= 0~)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I upgrade my machine to the latest HWE graphics stack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the multiarch upgrade command?  I see i386 packages on your post.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Multiarch_Desktop

> MULTIARCH DESKTOP
>
> If you run a multiarch desktop (for example, i386 and amd64 on amd64,
>   for gaming or Wine), you may find you need a slightly more involved
>   command, like this:
>
> `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-core-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial
>   xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-input-all-lts-xenial
>   libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial
>   libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial:i386`

Comment: Yep, that was it! My bad, I didn't see the trailing `i386` at the end of one of those lines. Wonder why I have a 32-bit package installed here.